# use button on form without submit

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I created a form in which I need to use these two  tags. My problem is that every time the user clicks on it, the form is submitted. I used onclick="return false" as follows, but the values ​​are not sent in the url Query.

```
                <div class="btn-group d-flex justify-content-center col-11 mx-auto" role="group">
                <button type="radio"  onclick="return false" name="type" value="rent" class="btn btn-lg btn-light pr-4 pl-4" id="left">YES</button>                       
                <button type="radio"  onclick="return false" name="type" value="sale" class="btn btn-lg btn-light pr-4 pl-4" id="right">NO</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-11 mx-auto">
                <button class="btn btn-block btn-danger">Submite</button>
            </div>
```

Comment: Try using event.preventDefault()

Comment: [How to prevent buttons from submitting forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent buttons from submitting forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms)

Answer (score 2):

> <button type="radio"

Radio buttons are `input` elements, not `button` elements. They are also empty/void elements which can't have children, so use a `label` element instead.

```html
<input type="radio" name="type" value="rent" class="btn btn-lg btn-light pr-4 pl-4" id="left">
<label for "left">Yes</label>
```

Note that screen reader software tends to read out content in all-caps letter-by-letter. Write in normal sentence case and use the CSS `text-transform` property to present it in upper-case instead.